# Использование слов "написание" или "письмо"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Хочу удостовериться в своей правоте. В предложении использовано слово "написанием", что, собственно, раздражает меня. Думаю, тут нужно использовать "письмом".
Нужны ваши подтверждения.

> *Вот тогда... [он] допустит или не допустит проявление созданных им способностей человека к письму, и осуществится деяние, называемое "написанием"*.
>   [**Предустановление и предведение**](http://islam.uz/islam/iyman/384-predustanovlenie-i.html)

Comment: Авазбек, если Вы даете цитату, то в ней ничего изменять нельзя! Нужно что-то "изничтожить" из текста - ставьте троеточие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это авторское право, выбрать тут нужное слово. Возможно, по контексту "написание" подходит больше. И это далеко не полные синонимы, не всегда взаимозаменяемые.

Письмо (как действие) может означать и способ нанесения письменных знаков на поверхность, и язык, на котором написано, и шрифт или стиль написания. Много всего, чего нет в "написании".

Написание (тоже как действие) не столь богато оттенками, относится больше к орфографии и форме букв, но зато точнее передает процесс ***рукописного*** действия (с использованием бумаги, чернил, пера или авторучки - или, скажем, шёлка, китайской туши и кисточки, стилоса, калама...).

Так что я бы не рекомендовал замену без консультации с автором. Или хотя бы контекста.

В любом случае "написание" не есть ошибка.